# Wave sort in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I have written a function to perform [wave-sort](https://programmingpraxis.com/2016/03/04/wave-sorting/) as shown below. The resulting array should begin with a number bigger than the next one but my code is not doing that. For example if the input is:

```
[73, 80, 40, 86, 14, 96, 10, 56, 61, 84, 82, 36, 85]
```

...it gives an output of

```
[ 86, 96, 84, 85, 80, 82, 61, 73, 40, 56, 14, 36, 10 ]
```

instead of starting with a bigger number than the next, which is `96`.

```
function waveSort(arr){
    arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b - a; 
    });

    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
        if (arr[i-1] > arr[i]) {
            var temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i-1];
            arr[i-1] = temp;
        }
        if (i+1 < arr.length && arr[i+1] > arr[i]) {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it should begin with a bigger value? You are in fact testing that in the first `if`, and if true, you swap the smaller value before the bigger one. What did you expect?

Comment: Is there a better solution for wavesort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have explicitly designed your function to start with a lower value.

In the first `if` you detect a situation where the first value is greater than the second, and if so, you swap them (when `i = 1`):

```
if (arr[i-1] > arr[i]) {
```

So it is normal you end up with a smaller value at index 0 than at index 1.

If you want your array to start with a "wave high", then change the conditions in your two `if`s:

```js
function waveSort(arr){
    arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b - a; 
    });

    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
        if (arr[i-1] < arr[i]) {
            var temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i-1];
            arr[i-1] = temp;
        }
        if (i+1 < arr.length && arr[i+1] < arr[i]) {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

var waved = waveSort([73, 80, 40, 86, 14, 96, 10, 56, 61, 84, 82, 36, 85]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(waved));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function waveSort(arr){
    arr.sort((a,b)=>b-a);
    for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i+=2){
        var tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[i+1];
        arr[i+1]=tmp;
    }
    return arr;
}
var wavesorted = waveSort([73, 80, 40, 86, 14, 96, 10, 56, 61, 84, 82, 36, 85]);
console.log(wavesorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to define a swap function and call it within the actual function like:

```js
const swap = (arr, i, j) => ([arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]]);

const waveSort = (arr) => {

  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => b - a);

for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 2){
    if(arr[i-1] < arr[i]) {
      swap(arr, i-1, i)
}
if(i+1 < arr.length && arr[i+1]  < arr[i]) {
      swap(arr, i+1, i)
}
}
return arr;
}

var waved = waveSort([73, 80, 40, 86, 14, 96, 10, 56, 61, 84, 82, 36, 85]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(waved));
```

`